# Why won't the grid columns expand to the entire width when I'm viewing this in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to figure out why I can't get this grid template to expand and/or even center the viewport. It works fine and as expected in desktop view...

Any ideas? Let me know if you require any more code snippets.

[image: here is a screenshot of the problem]

```
.grid-container-columns {

height: 100%;

display: grid;

grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);

grid-gap: 16px;

align-content: stretch;

}

header#home-section h1 {

grid-column: 3/span 8;

justify-self: center;

align-self: center;

text-align: center;

padding-top: 10rem;

z-index: 1;

}
```

The container div just provides a max-width of 1100px with a margin 0 auto.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your grid is actually adapting to the screen, but have an element overflowing the grid, which most likely is the title or the word "Personalize", it simply doesn't *fit* in the screen, you should try handling the font-size of that particular element so it adapts better, not the grid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to remove those blank spaces inbetween? If so, change

```
grid-gap: 16px;
```

to

```
grid-gap: 0;
```

Or even beter remove it completely if you don't use it.
Also to center it, you'll need

```
html, body{
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Here is some more context: if you see the image above, to the right of the grid there is a giant gap - not sure where that is coming from (the inspector doesn't even show what it is...)  I'm fine with the grid gap itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, so I noticed your h1 is too big. It is bigger than the screen, thus it overflows. Have you tried the overflow: hidden? This solves the gap to the right. You still need to decrease your font weight to make it fit the screen.

Comment: Awesome! That seemed to have fixed it (not sure how I could have missed that)...Now I just need to figure out how to make the font more responsive. Thanks again!

Comment: Yeah, would definitely avoid using `overflow: hidden`, just try to handle the font-size a bit better, since using the former rule might cause you other issues :) it is just a workaround, not really a solution

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what u want but from the description i understood that your body content is not adapting to mobile screen.Please remove following div class

```
<div class="grid-container-columns grid-container-two-rows">
```

and put only `grid-container` class and also why u want the bootstrap container
Please frame your questions so that people can understood what u expect add extra description and code.

Comment: I am trying to get the container to expand to the extent of the mobile viewport...To the right of the grid there is a giant gap (see image above). I'm not sure what you mean in your comment on bootstrap container...I'm not using bootstrap on this project (I'm creating a class to help with creating grids later on in my project which is a preference of mine, if that's what you're asking)